# How do you draw a line from the last position of the mouse to the present position of the mouse?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So, I'm creating some drawing maker thing, but when I move the mouse it doesn't draw circles in a line. I don't know how to say it well, but I want it to draw a line from point A (last position of mouse) to point B (present position of mouse).

Start drawing here and you will understand:

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

function pen(e, colorHEX) {
    let mouseX = e.clientX
    let mouseY = e.clientY
    
    ctx.fillStyle = colorHEX
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(mouseX, mouseY, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
}

$('body').mousedown(function(eObj){
    $('body').mousemove(function(e) {
        pen(e, '#000000')
    })
})

$('body').mouseup(function(eObj) {
    $('body').unbind('mousemove')
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: on mouse down get coordinates.  move mouse and on mouse up get coordinates.  Now calculate formula for line y=mx + b.  Then loop through points to create line

Comment: Umm... Can you explain that slower please? I don't understand. In code if you can.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're trying to draw a contiguous line (you don't need to do that by painting circles). You'll need to store the last mouse position, and then draw a line from there to the current mouse position.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

let lastPos // state variable

function pen(e, colorHEX) {
     
    const pos = {x:e.clientX, y: e.clientY}
    lastPos = (lastPos || pos) // Default to current pos
    
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.strokeStyle = colorHEX
    ctx.lineWidth = 1
    ctx.moveTo(lastPos.x, lastPos.y)
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y)
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.closePath()

    // Update the state variable
    lastPos = pos
}

$('body').mousedown(function(eObj){
    $('body').mousemove(function(e) {
        pen(e, '#000000')
    })
})

$('body').mouseup(function(eObj) {
    $('body').unbind('mousemove')
    lastPos = undefined
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This works great, but when I add circles, it breaks. Because, if you wanted just a dot on the screen, it would look like a line, but the user wanted a dot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the lineTo method

To make it move while you are dragging the line will take an extra script that includes angles and math.

```js
const c = document.getElementById('c')
const ctx = c.getContext('2d')

c.height = window.innerHeight
c.width = window.innerWidth

let startX;
let startY;





function pen(e, colorHEX) {
    let endX = e.clientX
    let endY = e.clientY
    
    ctx.fillStyle = colorHEX
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.moveTo(startX, startY)
    ctx.lineTo(endX, endY)
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.closePath()
    ctx.stroke()
}

$('body').mousedown(function(e){
    startX = e.clientX;
    startY = e.clientY;
})

$('body').mouseup(function(e) {
    pen(e, "#000000");
})
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="c"></canvas>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want it to make a line, but I want it to make a line made out of _circles_, but it doesn't have to be a straight line. A - - - - - - - - - - B

Answer (score 0):

## Drawing with mouse

### You have two options.

1. Draw a line segment from A to B setting the line width to match the circles diameter and the line cap to round.
2. Interpolate the points from A to B drawing a circle (or any shape) at points 1px apart.
3. I said two but there are a zillion ways to do this type of thing, but that would put this answer in the TLDR category.

Which method you use will depend on the finer details of your needs. The two example below drawing using the most basic solid line look identical.

What I think you may be having a problem with is because you are turning the event listeners on and off, the last mouse position you have is the last mouse up.

I have added two examples. One for each of the drawing options, and the top one uses an always on mouse listeners and a second turns on and of the mouse listeners as needed.

### Examples

The mouse has its state put into an object called `mouse`.

Each time the mouse changes position the last position is put into `mouse.lastX`, `mouse.lastY`.

If the mouse `event.type` is `mousedown` the `mouse.button` is set to `true` and to `false` if `mouseup`

Mouse up and down are also used to turn on and off things like cursor, add and remove events (second example)

At the bottom of the listener it checks if the mouse is down  (`mouse.button` is `true`) and draws a line from the last position to the current position.

#### Using line segments

- Draws by using 2D API's stroke function.
- Use always on mouse listeners.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
const BORDER = 1;  // I added a 1px border to canvas.
c.height = innerHeight - BORDER * 2;
c.width = innerWidth - BORDER * 2;
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, lastX: 0, lastY: 0, button: false};
function drawLine(xA, yA, xB, yB, col, width) {
    ctx.strokeStyle = col;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.lineWidth = width;

    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.lineTo(xA, yA);
    ctx.lineTo(xB, yB);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function mouseEvent(e) {
    if (e.type === "mousedown") { 
        mouse.button = true; 
        c.classList.add("hideMouse");
    } else if (e.type === "mouseup") { 
        mouse.button = false;
        c.classList.remove("hideMouse");
    }

    mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
    mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.clientX - BORDER;
    mouse.y = e.clientY - BORDER;

    if (mouse.button) {        
        drawLine(mouse.lastX, mouse.lastY, mouse.x, mouse.y, "#000", 4);
    }
}
addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvent);
addEventListener("mouseup",   mouseEvent); 
addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
.hideMouse {
    cursor: none;
}
div {
    background: #FFF8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;    
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<div>Click and drag mouse to draw</div>
```

#### Interpolate line

- Replaces `drawLine` function body with interpolation algorithum.
- Adds mouse listeners `mousemove` and `mouseup`, on `mousedown`. Note that the up listener has the option `{once:true}` when added so does not need to be manually removed.

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
const BORDER = 1;  // I added a 1px border to canvas.
c.height = innerHeight - BORDER * 2;
c.width = innerWidth - BORDER * 2;
const mouse = {x: 0, y: 0, lastX: 0, lastY: 0, button: false};

function drawLine(xA, yA, xB, yB, col, width) {
    var i = 0;
    const dx = xB - xA;
    const dy = yB - yA;
    const length = Math.hypot(dx, dy);
    const stepX = length > 0 ? dx / length : 0;
    const stepY = length > 0 ? dy / length : 0;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.fillStyle = col;
    while (i <= length) {
        ctx.moveTo(xA + width / 2, yA);
        ctx.arc(xA, yA, width / 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
        xA += stepX;
        yA += stepY;
        i ++;            
    }
    ctx.fill();
}

function mouseEvent(e) {
    if (e.type === "mousedown") { 
        mouse.button = true; 
        c.classList.add("hideMouse");
        addEventListener("mouseup",   mouseEvent, {once: true});
        addEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent);

        // Set mouse pos so last pos is not where the last mouse up was
        mouse.x = e.clientX - BORDER;
        mouse.y = e.clientY - BORDER;
    } else if (e.type === "mouseup") { 
        mouse.button = false;
        c.classList.remove("hideMouse");
        removeEventListener("mousemove", mouseEvent);
    }

    mouse.lastX = mouse.x;
    mouse.lastY = mouse.y;
    mouse.x = e.clientX - BORDER;
    mouse.y = e.clientY - BORDER;

    if (mouse.button) {        
        drawLine(mouse.lastX, mouse.lastY, mouse.x, mouse.y, "#000", 4);          
    }
}
addEventListener("mousedown", mouseEvent);
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    font-family: arial;
}
canvas {
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
.hideMouse {
    cursor: none;
}
div {
    background: #FFF8;
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 4px;    
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="c"></canvas>
 <div>Click and drag mouse to draw</div>
```

#### Side note...

**jQuery is dead**

BTW jQuery is not needed, it became irrelevant about 5 years ago.

Using it puts you many years behind modern front end development.

In the past 5 years the demand for jQuery experience coders has dropped a significant amount. A trend that will continue as jQuery has painted its self into a corner from which the only way out is via re branding and re targeting its purpose.

Every time you use jQuery you are investing your most valuable asset, time. Time spent learning and gaining experience. Be wise and direct that time learning what is applicable and growing in the future, and not into what started dying over a decade ago.

For more details [Should you use or learn jQuery in 2020?](https://flaviocopes.com/jquery/)